# accessing private data members from the outside class using pointers

Tags: c++

As I understand, private data members are only accessible from within the class. There is a way in which I can access or change the private data of a class but doing so violates the object oriented programming concepts. The following code would help you out as to how to access the private data members.

```
class sample
{    
private:      
    int i;

public:    
    sample(int a)
    {    
        i=a;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
};

void main()
{
    sample s(97);
    s.display();
    int *p=(int*)&s;
    *p=43;
    s.display();
}
```

So here we can easily access the data at that address which is nothing but the private data. Am I right?

Comment: The presence of the cast should already be raising alarm bells.

Comment: *C++ is designed to protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli* (Bjarne Stroustrup)